# Why does the page display text saying "[object Object]" instead of the actual page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bun

everyone! I'm an amateur at web design (both frontend and backend) and I wanted to make a project, basically a Google Clone. At the same time, Bun was also getting popular, so I decided to use it for my website (also using React and Typescript, of course). I watched this video about Bun, Elysia and React so I decided to copy some code just for a test drive.

When I ran the website, I was shocked to find that all that it had render was `[object Object]` and I was confused. I tried Googling the answer but I couldn't find any result that could resolve my problem. So I went here to present my problem.

Here's my code so you can actually debug the problem:

```
import { Elysia } from "elysia";
import { html } from "@elysiajs/html";
import * as elements from "typed-html";

const app = new Elysia()
  .use(html())
  .get("/", ({ html }) => 
    html(
      <Index>
        <body>
          <h1> hi </h1>
        </body> 

      </Index>
    )
  )
  .listen(3000);

console.log(`App running at ${app.server?.hostname}:${app.server?.port}`);

const Index = ({ children }: elements.Children) => `
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title> Coolgle: The Better Google </title>
    </head>
    ${children}
  </html>
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and seems like the problem is that you're missing the backticks in:

```html
<Index>

  <body>
    <h1> hi </h1>
  </body>

</Index>
```

This is working for me:

```js
import { Elysia } from "elysia";
import { html } from "@elysiajs/html";
import * as elements from "typed-html";

const app = new Elysia()
  .use(html())
  .get("/", ({ html }) =>
    html(
      `<Index>
        <body>
          <h1> hi </h1>
        </body>
      </Index>`
    )
  )
  .listen(3000);

console.log(`App running at ${app.server?.hostname}:${app.server?.port}`);

const Index = ({ children }: elements.Children) => `
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title> Coolgle: The Better Google </title>
    </head>
    ${children}
  </html>
`;
```

I hope this helps!